# Change spring boot snapshot/build version

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build, executable-jar

I have a requirement to change the build version in my spring boot application everytime I commit the code. But it should not be by changing the Pom.XML or application.properties file. Can someone please help how can this be achieved.

Comment: `But it should not be by changing the Pom.XML` that does not really makes sense... to make it clear everytime you build or everytime you change your project (means change in version control?)

Comment: I meant I don’t want to modify Pom.xml with every build. I have got the solution now by using maven build number plugin.

Comment: Do you change the code or config in any way to trigger a new build? If yes that means a change in your project ...which should represented by changing a version (semver:?)...

Comment: Yes that’s right. New version means change in the code. I just wanted to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this by using buildnumber maven plugin. It generates the build number automatically which get updated in builder.properties file.
So I don’t have to change it manually in Pom.XML everytime.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).